# Can we show $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin nx}{e^{nx}}=0$ does not hold for $x<0, x\not\in \Bbb Z\pi$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> Can we show $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin nx}{e^{nx}}=0$ does not hold for $x<0, x\not\in \Bbb Z\pi$.

Let $f(n)=\frac{\sin nx}{e^{nx}}$.

If $-\pi<x<0$, pick $\delta=x/2$, then the inteveral $I_k=[\frac{2k\pi+\delta/2}{|x|},\frac{2k\pi+\pi-\delta/2}{|x|}]$ has length $1$, and $\exists\ n_k\in\Bbb Z_+,st n_k\in I_k$, so $f(n_k)\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. The result holds.

What about $(m-1)\pi<x<m\pi, m\in-\Bbb Z_+=\{-1,-2,\cdots\}$. It seems the method above fails.

Comment: @Surb Why? As $x\to m\pi$, it semms wrong.

Comment: @Surb Why then?can you give a hint?

Comment: Are you sure your inequality is true? @Surb

Comment: @aschepler If $\;x>0\;$ then $\;\frac1{e^{nx}}\to 0\;$ and $\;\sin nx\;$ is bounded, so the limit is zero...

Comment: @aschepler I know. You just wrote "for every $\;x\;$", so I though you meant that...

Comment: Does my answer, answer your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume throughout that $x<0$ and $x\not\in \mathbb{Z}\pi$, then we have the following two facts:

- The sequence of functions $f_{n}=1/\exp(nx)$ is unbounded.
- The sequence $g_{n}=\sin(nx)$ can not converge to $0$.

*Proof of the second fact*:
Suppose it did then $$0=\lim g_{n}=\lim g_{n+1}=\lim \cos x\sin (nx)+\sin(x) \cos(nx)$$ Thereby meaning that $ \lim \cos(nx)=0$, but that is in contradiction with the fact that:$\sin(nx)^2+\cos(nx)^2=1$.

These two facts imply that the limit of  $f_{n}g_{n}$ does not exist.

Comment: "If $\sin(nx) \neq 0$" says something about a specific $n$, so I don't see how you then imply something about the entire sequence $g_n$. What do you mean by $\lim g_{n+1} \to \lim \cos(nx)$, and why would it be true?

Comment: Which double angle formula, and how? I still don't see anything forcing a $\cos$ value to be small.

Comment: Consider the sin double angle formula on $g_{n+1}$

Comment: @aschepler What did you get? Letting $n$ go to infinity can’t you see why the cosine value must be small?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142997/discussion-between-aschepler-and-shinrin-yoku).

Comment: I can't see any problem with this answer so far: if we assume $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin nx=0\;$ , then as  Shinrin says we'd get that also $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin((n+1)x)=0\;$ , of course. But then using the well known trigonometric identity we have:

$$0=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin((n+1)x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sin nx\cos x+\sin x\cos nx\right)$$

and since $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin nx\cos x=0\;$, it must be that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin x\cos nx=0\;$ , by arithmetic of limits.

Comment: (cont.) Thus we'd have that (since $\;\cos x\;$ is a non-zero constant) 

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin nx=0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos nx$$ and this would be true for any constant $\;x<0\;$ . But his is impossible, as he remarks, since $$1=\lim_{n\to\infty}1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sin^2nx+\cos^2nx\right)\stackrel{\text{arit. of limits}}=0+0=0 ...\text{contradiction} $$

Comment: @DonAntonio So you agree with me, yet I got downvoted :-(

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Well, I could be wrong, of course....but I think many people have a light finger on the keyboard. I don't downvote even if the question is wrong. We all deserve a second chance to improve something, even if we made a mistake. I shall upvote your answer ot make things even.

Comment: @DonAntonio You are right, I should not have assumed ill intention.